# php How to make a proper hash function that will handle given strings

Tags: php, hash

I want to create a hash function that will receive strings and output the corresponding value in an array that has predefined "proportions". For instance, if my array holds the values:

```
[0] => "output number 1"
[1] => "output number 2"
[2] => "output number 3"
```

Then the hash function `int H(string)` should return only values in the range `0` and `2` for any given string (an input string will always return the same key).

The thing is that i want it to also make judgement by predefined proportions so, for instance
`85%` of given strings will hash out as `0`, `10%` as `1` and `5%` as `2`. If there are functions that can emulate normal distribution that will be even better.

I also want it to be fast as it will run frequently. Can someone point me to the right direction on how to approach this in php? I believe I'm not the first one that asked this but I came short digging on SO for an hour.

**EDIT:**

What i did until now is built a hash function in `c`. It does the above hashing without proportions (still not comfortable with php):

```
int StringFcn (const void *key, size_t arrSize)
{
    char *str = key;
    int totalAsciiVal = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        totalAsciiVal += *str++;
    }

    return totalAsciiVal % arrSize;
}
```

Comment: So what have YOU tried in order to implement this?

Comment: Interesting proposition. Your question is definitely not PHP centric, however. It lies more in the theoretical realm. Also, I'm not sure you've given enough information on the range of expected inputs & outputs. What do you mean by 'normal distribution'? Because your example 85/10/5 split doesn't match any definition of normal I know of.

Comment: @PatrickM I'm not too concerned about the distribution function if it can't simulate normal distribution (my thought was since the number of inputs I'm expecting is 3 to 50 then if I pass 30 it will be large enough for normal distribution).

Comment: @MikeBrant I edited the question Mike sorry for that

Comment: by normal distribution i mean the statistical normal distribution `X~N`

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this:

```
// Hash the string so you can pretty much guarantee it will have a number in it and it is relatively "random"
$hash = sha1($string);

// Iterate through string and get ASCII values
$chars = str_split($hash);
$num = 0;
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    $num += ord($int);
}

// Get compare modulo 100 of the number
if ($num % 100 < 85) {
    return 0;
}
if ($num % 100 < 95) {
    return 1;
}
return 2;
```

**Edit:**

Instead of hashing with `sha1`, you can get a sufficiently large integer directly using [crc32](http://php.net/crc32) (thanks to @nivrig in the comments).

```
// Convert string to integer
$num = crc32($string);

// Get compare modulo 100 of the number
if ($num % 100 < 85) {
    return 0;
}
if ($num % 100 < 95) {
    return 1;
}
return 2;
```

Comment: I posted this before I noticed the edit to your question. It looks like this is pretty close to what you're doing too, except for the modulo part. I think I like your idea about getting the ascii values since it means you will have more numbers.

Comment: Hey @Mike thanks. I'm definitely looking for something that will be fast. I thing doing regex is an overkill. I would rather make manipulation on bit values or something of that sort if it's possible?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use crc32(). to get an int from the string directly to feed in to the modulo and it would be much faster than sha1